# Окна с QRadioButton и QCheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qradiobutton, qmessagebox

Имеется два приложения:

1. Окно на основе `QRadioButton` - модуль **radio.py**.
2. Окно на основе `QCheckBox`  - модуль **chech.py**.

***Трудности***: не получается в первом окне с `QRadioButton` реализовать иконку через `setIcon()` и нижнею отсечку кнопок (как на примере: на изображении №2). 
Предполагаю что проблема в class’е.

**1.** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]     **2.** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** предложения по улучшению кода приветствуются.

---

**radio.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QButtonGroup, QRadioButton,)


class Widg(QWidget, object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widg, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')
        # self.setIcon(self.Information)
        label_tk = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_tk.setText('     Необходимо выбрать браузер \n      \n ')
        label_p = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label_p.setText('  ')

        self._dictRB = {
            'Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)': False,
            'PhantomJS Driver': False,
            'rad3': False,
        }

        self.group = QButtonGroup()
        self.rad1 = QRadioButton("Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)")
        self.rad2 = QRadioButton("PhantomJS Driver")
        self.rad3 = QRadioButton("rad3")

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Старт')
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btn1_Clicked(self.rad1.isChecked()))
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Отмена')
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_Clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label_tk)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad2)
        layout.addWidget(label_p)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn2)

        self.group.addButton(self.rad1)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad2)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad3)
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def check_button(self, radioButton):
        if self._dictRB[radioButton.text()]:
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = False
            self._dictRB['rad3'] = True
            self.rad2.setChecked(True)
        else:
            for b in self._dictRB:
                self._dictRB[b] = False
            self._dictRB[radioButton.text()] = True
        print("Нажата кнопка -> `{} ` - {}".format(radioButton.text(), radioButton.isChecked()))
        return radioButton

    def btn1_Clicked(self, radioButton):
        for b in self._dictRB:
            if self._dictRB[b] is False:
                pass
            elif radioButton:
                print('выбран: Coogle Chrome')
                # import image_chrome
                break
            else:
                print(' выбран: PhantomJS Driver')
                # import image
                break
        self.close()

    def btn2_Clicked(self):
        print(' нажата кнопка: отмена')
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Widg()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**chech.py**

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QCheckBox, QMessageBox, )
from PyQt5.QtCore import (pyqtSlot, )

class MessageBox(QtWidgets.QMessageBox, QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Внимание!")
        self.setIcon(self.Critical)
        self.addButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Удалить'), QtWidgets.QMessageBox.YesRole)
        self.addButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Отмена'), QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoRole)
        self.addCheckBox(self)

        currentClick = self.exec_()
        if currentClick == 0:
            print(' нажата кнопка = Удалить')
            print()

            if self.check1.isChecked() == False and \
               self.check2.isChecked() == False and \
               self.check3.isChecked() == False:
               self.not_del()
            else:
                if self.check1.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (1. ) =', self.check1.isChecked())
                    self.del_Doc()

                if self.check2.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (2. ) =', self.check2.isChecked())
                    self.del_Otv()

                if self.check3.isChecked() == True:
                    print(' значение CheckBox (3. ) =', self.check3.isChecked())
                    self.del_Im()
            self.message()
        if currentClick == 1:
            print(' нажата кнопка = Отмена')

    def addCheckBox(self, parentItem):
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lb1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Файлы удалятся безвозвратно. \n              Вы уверены?", self)
        lb1.setGeometry(60, 15, 300, 40)
        lb2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Следующие данные будут удалены:', self)
        lb2.setGeometry(20, 60, 350, 20)

        self._toggle = True
        self.check1 = QCheckBox('1.', self)
        self.check1.setGeometry(20, 85, 200, 20)
        self.check1.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check2 = QCheckBox('2.', self)
        self.check2.setGeometry(20, 105, 200, 20)
        self.check2.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check3 = QCheckBox('3.', self)
        self.check3.setGeometry(20, 125, 200, 20)
        self.check3.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check = QCheckBox('Выбрать все папки', self)
        self.check.setGeometry(20, 155, 200, 20)
        self.check.setChecked(self._toggle)

        self.check1.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check2.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check3.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.check.clicked.connect(self.chec_toggle)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def chec_toggle(self):
        if self.sender() == self.check:
            if self._toggle == True:
                self.check1.setChecked(self._toggle)
                self.check2.setChecked(self._toggle)
                self.check3.setChecked(self._toggle)
            else:
                self.check1.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check2.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check3.setChecked(not self._toggle)
                self.check.setChecked(not self._toggle)

        elif self.sender() in (self.check1, self.check2, self.check3):
            self.check.setChecked(not self._toggle)

    def del_Doc(self): pass
    def del_Otv(self): pass
    def del_Im(self): pass

    def not_del(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')
        msgBox.setText("   Ни одна папка не выбрана!   ")
        msgBox.exec_()

    def message(self):
        msgBox0 = QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox0.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox0.setText('Операция очистки завершена.  ')
        msgBox0.exec_()

    def event(self, e):
        result = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.event(self, e)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMaximumHeight(16777215)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.resize(250, 230)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MessageBox()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**QLabel**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#details) используется для отображения текста или изображения. Функциональность взаимодействия с пользователем не предусмотрена. Внешний вид метки можно настроить различными способами, и ее можно использовать для указания мнемонической клавиши фокуса для другого виджета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**radio.py**

```
import sys
# ??? from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, 
    QButtonGroup, QRadioButton, QLabel, QApplication, QMessageBox,
    QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# ??? ----------------> vvvvvv
# ? class Widg(QWidget, object):
class Widg(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widg, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Внимание!')
        
        label_tk = QLabel()
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        label_tk.setText('''
          <p> 
            <img src="smiley.gif" alt="icon face" 
             width="42" height="42" 
             style="vertical-align:top"> 
            Необходимо выбрать браузер.
          </p>
         ''')
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        self.label_p = QLabel()
        
# ?         label_p.setText('  ')
# ?        self._dictRB = {
# ?            'Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)': False,
# ?            'PhantomJS Driver': False,
# ?            'rad3': False,
# ?        }

        self.check_button = None                                        # !!! +++

        self.group = QButtonGroup()
        self.rad1 = QRadioButton("Coogle Chrome (рекомендуется)")
        self.rad2 = QRadioButton("PhantomJS Driver")
        self.rad3 = QRadioButton("rad3")                                  # ?

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Старт')
# ?        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btn1_Clicked(self.rad1.isChecked()))
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_clicked)                     # !!! +++
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Отмена')
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label_tk, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad1)
        layout.addWidget(self.rad2)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_p)
        
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.btn1)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.btn2)
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)

        self.group.addButton(self.rad1)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad2)
        self.group.addButton(self.rad3)
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.group_check_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)
# ?        self.show()

# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def group_check_button(self, rb):
        self.check_button = rb

    def btn1_clicked(self):                            # ?  , radioButton):
        if not self.check_button:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Вы не сделали выбор?')
            return
        print(f'Выбран: {self.check_button.text()}')
        self.label_p.setText(f'Выбран: {self.check_button.text()}')
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def btn2_clicked(self):
        print('Нажата кнопка: отмена')
        self.close()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widg()
    w.resize(250, 250)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

У вас есть проблемы с вашим вторым модулем **chech.py**, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Tusher что не так?

Comment: Спасибо, ответ помог. Жаль, что функционал не предусмотрен. А может ест другие варианты в тело `QMessageBox` встроить `QradioButton`?

Comment: @Tusher пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour  Я не понял чего вам жаль и какой функционал не предусмотрен? Всегда есть и другие варианты, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Возможно ли в тело QMessageBox встроить QradioButton?

Comment: @Tusher sorry. я же вам написал - примите решение по текущему вопросу и хадайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Не будет ли это считаться дублем уже имеющейся темы? Если перефразирую вопрос, не получится, что и эту тему закроют, и новую?